# How to make a MovieClip remove itself in AS3?

Tags: flash-cs4, actionscript-3, movieclip

What is the equivalent to `removeMovieClip()` in AS3?

Apparently many have the same question:
StackOverflow:

1. [How to completely remove a movieclip in as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102176/how-to-completely-remove-a-movieclip-in-as3)
2. [Remove movie clip as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253803/remove-movie-clip-as3)
3. [How to remove childmovieclip and add  to  new parent movieclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939115/how-to-remove-childmovieclip-and-add-to-new-parent-movieclip)

Others:

1. [removeMovieClip(this) in AS3?](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=748039)
2. [Destroy/Delete a Movieclip???](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=590100)
3. [Remove movie clip](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=141528)

But none of their solutions seem to work, for me:

Im working on **flash CS4** with **AS3**:

I have a very simple movie with a single button called *click*. On pressing the button, a new instance of *coin* is created:

```
this.click.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,justclick);
function justclick(e:MouseEvent){
    var money=new coin
    this.addChild(money)
    money.x=e.stageX
    money.y=e.stageY
}
```

It might not be the best code, but it works fine. Now, the coin MovieClip is supposed to show a small animation and remove itself. In good old AS2 I would have added:

```
this.removeMovieClip()
```

in the last frame of the animation. But this doesn't exist in AS3.
I have tried, without success:

```
this.parent.removeChild(this) // 'Cannot access a property or method of nullobject reference'...     

this.removeMovieClip() // 'removeMovieClip is not a function'      

removeMovieClip(this) //'call to possibly undefined method removeMovieClip'       

unloadMovie(this)//'call to possibly undefined method removeMovieClip'
```

Solutions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
this.parent.removeChild(this);
```

This one should be working; it's what I use. One problem I had when I switched to AS3 is that sometimes it wouldn't be added as a child right, so you might want to check that. You also have to import flash.display via putting this at the top if you're not already:

```
import flash.display.*
```

You should also remove the event listener on it before removing it.

Comment: Thanks, it was about the event listeners. Now it works perfectly.

BTW what is ´import flash.display.*´ for?

Comment: It lets you use functions from the classes inside of the display package that comes with flash.


btw, if someone solves your problem you should accept that answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your animation is ending on frame 20.

note: using 19 because flash count frames from zero(0) similar to array index.

```
class animatedCloud
{

    public function animatedCloud(){
        addFrameScript(19, frame20);
    }

    private function frame20(){
        parent.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always ensure that those self removing movieclips can get garbage collected. 
This solution wiped away all my instances from a loaded swf's library symbol:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new definition() as MovieClip;
addChild(mc);

mc.x = 1000 * Math.random();
mc.y = 1000 * Math.random();

mc.addFrameScript(mc.totalFrames - 1, function onLastFrame():void
{
    mc.stop();
    mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
    mc = null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function removeDisplayObject(displayObject:DisplayObject):void {
    /* normal code
    if(displayObject && displayObject.parent){
        displayObject.parent.removeChild(displayObject);
    }
     */
    displayObject ? displayObject.parent ? displayObject.parent.removeChild(displayObject) : null : null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use, in an extra blank keyframe at the end of the MovieClip which should remove itself:

```
stop();
MovieClip(parent).removeChild(this);
```

Found it to be the proper and best solution.